# How to set the value of select in admin config Magento2

Tags: magento2, adminhtml

I am creating multi-column config, the problem is it's only setting the value of the first select field, the second field is not being selected following is my code :

```
<?php   
namespace Aayanshtech\Adminsection\Block\System\Config\Form\Field;

use Magento\Config\Block\System\Config\Form\Field\FieldArray\AbstractFieldArray;

/**
 * Class Active
 *
 * @package Aayanshtech\Adminsection\Block\System\Config\Form\Field
 */
class Fields extends AbstractFieldArray {

    /**
     * @var bool
     */
    protected $_addAfter = TRUE;

    /**
     * @var
     */
    protected $_addButtonLabel;
    protected $_activation;
    protected $_sec_one_action;

    /**
     * Construct
     */
    protected function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Option');
    }
    /**
     * Get activation options.
     *
     * @return \Magently\Tutorial\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Activation
     */
    protected function _getActivationRenderer()
    {
        if (!$this->_activation) {
            $this->_activation = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                '\Aayanshtech\Adminsection\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Activation',
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }

        return $this->_activation;
   }
   protected function _getActivationRenderer2()
   {
        if (!$this->_sec_one_action) {
            $this->_sec_one_action = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
                '\Aayanshtech\Adminsection\Block\Adminhtml\Form\Field\Seconeaction',
                '',
                ['data' => ['is_render_to_js_template' => true]]
            );
        }

        return $this->_sec_one_action;
   }
    /**
     * Prepare to render the columns
     */
    protected function _prepareToRender() {
        $this->addColumn('field_1', ['label' => __('Distance')]);
        $this->addColumn('field_2', ['label' => __('Code')]);
        $this->addColumn('field_3', ['label' => __('Selection order')]);
        $this->addColumn('field_4', ['label' => __('Price')]);
        $this->addColumn(
            'field_5',
            [
                'label' => __('Type of price'),
                'renderer' => $this->_getActivationRenderer()
            ]
        );
        $this->addColumn(
            'field_6',
            [
                'label' => __('Action'),
                'renderer' => $this->_getActivationRenderer2()
            ]
        );
        $this->_addAfter       = FALSE;
        $this->_addButtonLabel = __('Add Option');
    }
    /**
     * Prepare existing row data object.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\DataObject $row
     * @return void
     */
    protected function _prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $options = [];
        if($row->getData('field_5')){
            $customAttribute = $row->getData('field_5');
            $key = 'option_' . $this->_getActivationRenderer()->calcOptionHash($customAttribute);
            $options[$key] = 'selected="selected"';
            $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
        }
        if($row->getData('field_6')){
            $customAttribute = $row->getData('field_6');
            $key = 'option_' . $this->_getActivationRenderer()->calcOptionHash($customAttribute);
            $options[$key] = 'selected="selected"';
            $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
        }

    }


}
```

I got stuck `_prepareArrayRow` in this function what i want to achieve please see the screen shot.[image]

Unable to set the value of action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I missed with the following code in `_prepareArrayRow(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)` function

It should be `_getActivationRenderer2` instead of `_getActivationRenderer` :

```
if($row->getData('field_6')){
            $customAttribute = $row->getData('field_6');
            $key = 'option_' . $this->_getActivationRenderer2()->calcOptionHash($customAttribute);
            $options[$key] = 'selected="selected"';
            $row->setData('option_extra_attrs', $options);
        }
```